# How to get through the browser web page source code does not have the data

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I use  Firefox browser to crawl data by selenium , I can see the data in interpret of the browser, but there is no target data in the page_source(), there is JavaScript code, how do I get the desired data

url：
https://www.chinastock.com.cn/service/faq.do?methodCall=faqDetail&name=jlj&catId=178#mark178

Comment: `driver.page_source`

Comment: Which `data` are you looking for? Your _code trials_ and the relevant _HTML_ please.

Comment: Question and answer         driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://www.chinastock.com.cn/service/faq.do?methodCall=faqDetail&name=neptune20&catId=167#mark167')


time.sleep(5)
print(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[3]//text()'))



driver.quit()

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you provided it seems to me you want to extract the text from inside a webelement?

-- First of all, getting a text value from a Webelement is not possible when using `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` as it returns a list, use `driver.find_element_by_xpath` instead.

-- Second, do `driver.find_element_by_xpath` first, then add `.get_attribute("innerText")` at the end.

`driver.find_element_by_xpath.get_attribute("innerText")`